# VBA control over the ribbon?

Tags: excel, ribbon, vba

I am in the process of creating a VBA add-in for Excel 2010, and I used the "[Custom UI Editor for Microsoft Office](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2009/08/07/7293.aspx)" tool to create my own ribbon. 
However, I would like to give the user the option to load my add-in without displaying the ribbon, or with different parts of the ribbon visible.

With menus, I know you can completely control them programmatically, but ribbons seem to work differently.

Is there a way in VBA to *not* load my `customUI.xml` ribbon tabs on startup?
Is there a way to remove items from (or add items to) these tabs at runtime?

Comment: Hey Josh, here is a whole slew of help on this subject <http://www.rondebruin.nl/ribbon.htm> I think points 2 and 3 are of particular interest to you.

Comment: Thanks; maybe my googling wasn't great. The link is a 404 but I followed it to the right place...http://www.rondebruin.nl/tips.htm and more specifically: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee390805(office.11).aspx  I will take a look through these links.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman can you please post this as an answer so I can mark it as best?  I haven't 100% solved the issue yet, but at least I am seeing some examples of how to interact with the Ribbon.

Comment: How about once you solve the issue, you post the answer and mark it as the best! :) That will help more people, I believe.

Comment: What I mean is.. I have the tools now. I can definitely make the ribbon invisible with what I learned from the link you gave me.  Conditionally making it visible is just a short hop away (almost there..), and my main trouble is in handling some very project-specific parameters that are outside the scope of the question.

Comment: Okay. I will accept your offer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

here is a whole slew of help on this subject [Awesome Ribbon Help](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/section2.htm). I think points 2 and 3 are of particular interest to you.

Comment: This is an invaluable resource. Thanks again!

Comment: This will be circulated to my colleagues, as we lurch towards the 2010 Migration.

Comment: @Andrew -> if you read Ron's message on the site, you can search the menu to find the answer page you seek.