# Excel VBA: How to turn code into a full on toolbar tool?

Tags: vba, button, excel, add-in, toolbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [VBA control over the ribbon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005621/vba-control-over-the-ribbon)

It's amateur-hour here at home again and I could use some assistance.

So I've written up about five real nifty pieces of code to perform set tasks for me on a massive level. I've decided they're useful and I'd like to use them for quite a bit more in the future and I'd like to send them to some colleagues of mine.

Problem: I have to import the modules I've made into each project and its not too big of a deal but I'd like them more readily available.

Goal: I would like to make a toolbar that is permanantly on my toolbar ribbon in excel with a button for each of the five modules I've made so all I have to do is click on the button and it sets the said module off running.

How would I go about beginning to do such a task? Your input is much appreciated!!

Comment: See `XL Add-ins` and also this post from SO (which contatins a link for some great ribbon help) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005621/vba-control-over-the-ribbon#comment16015388_12005621

Comment: thanks a bunch Scott I was looking for a link like that!